# Disable text zoom feature in browser

Tags: browser, zooming, font-size

I want to disable the text zoom feature in the clients browser for certain sections of my website. Is this possible? Can I code the webpage for a specific font size which is not resized when the client chooses to do so?

Comment: i'm interested in why you'd want to do this..?

Comment: I've created a web application that lets users create their own photobook. Currently, users can view the result in Flash, and if they like what they see, they can order their book. Since Apple doesn't like flash, and I want to make it possible for iPad users to work with the application, I'm interested in converting the viewer to HTML. I've got it working now, but if a user uses magnified fonts, the result gets distorted.

Comment: We have the same problem. Modern webkits use CSS pixels that != device pixels when zoomed, but we have flash content and it uses device pixels even when zoomed, making it impossible to do pixel-perfect coordination between flash and html.